# How to successfully use pandas.Dataframe.apply with pandas.NA and lambdas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

Given a dataframe with a pandas.NA value, how can I run a decision lambda over it

```
import pandas
import numpy
# Setup
dataframe = pandas.DataFrame({"c1": [1, 2, 3, 4], "c2": [2, 3, 4, pandas.NA]})
print(dataframe)
my_lambda = lambda row: row["c2"] if row["c2"] else row["c1"]
```

[image: dataframe with pandas.NA]

```
# the issue
dataframe["c2"] = dataframe.apply(my_lambda, axis="columns")
```

Which raises TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous

How can I get this lambda to work over pandas.NA or can I force pandas.NA to numpy.NaN? (code will run if you replace pandas.NA with numpy.NaN)

The cause of this is because pandas.NA doesn't evaluate to True or False

```
if pandas.NA:
    print("no")
```

Raises the same Error

However

```
if pandas.NA in [pandas.NA]:
    print("yes")
```

Evaluates to true. But..

```
my_lambda = lambda row: row["c2"] if row["c2"] in [pandas.NA] else row ["c1"]
```

Still raises the error

Please consider the dataframe I work with are big 1k-1m rows.

Solutions I've considered that work but are suboptimal for my purpose.

- fillna(0) - fill value may be 0 or some other number. Then run lambda with fill value included in the search.
- replace() - same as above

These are suboptimal because values may be 0 or any other digit.

Solutions I've considered but couldn't work out how to actually get running.

- passing lambda to fillna() or replace() or some other function that can directly target the pandas.NA values
- forcing the column so that it contains numpy.NaN instead of pandas.NA (replace/fillna doesn't work as pandas.NA is a mask for numpy.NaN)

Both of these would be good solutions

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `dataframe['c2'] = dataframe['c2'].fillna(dataframe['c1'])` works fine

Comment: Thanks guys, I didn't really work out that you could throw another column or other from the dataframe into fillna.

Slightly more general solution I went with
```my_lambda = lambda dataframe: dataframe['c1'] 
\n
dataframe['c2'] = dataframe['c2'].fillna(my_lambda(dataframe))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just do

```
dataframe.apply(lambda row: row["c2"] if pd.notna(row["c2"]) else row["c1"], axis=1)
```

Or better

```
dataframe['c2'] = dataframe['c2'].fillna(dataframe['c1'])
```

Comment: Thanks, was unaware you could do NA inspection through pandas.notna